# update from select not run when i'm using row_number()

Tags: sql-server

I have query update from select like this

```
update a 
set a.DocRefNumber = b.code + '-' + rtrim(ltrim(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.transid DESC)))  
from tblCollateralTransaction a
inner join tblMappingDocumentType b
on b.DocumentDetail = a.documents
```

When I run this query, I receive error like this:

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not tesetd but you can try like this.

```
With UpdateData As
(
select rtrim(ltrim(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.transid DESC)))  as RN
from tblCollateralTransaction a
)    
Update a
set a.DocRefNumber = b.code + '-' + RN
From tblCollateralTransaction a
inner join tblMappingDocumentType b
on b.DocumentDetail = a.documents
```

Comment: when i run your query, ihave error like this, Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.